# Copying active spreadsheet to all spreadsheet documents in a folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I am attempting to copy an individual spreadsheet to all spreadsheet files within a folder. I could not figure out how to do it, so I am using a previous code I found that lists all of the files, but it ends up listing all of the files in my drive, not just in that folder.

Could I get assistance either in making a script to copy it to all files in a specific folder, or change it so that the below code shows only that of the folder it is in? From what I have seen/changed DriveApp.getFiles() should only be listing those files in the folder?

```
function List()
{
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.setTitle("Copy Sheet in Multiple Spreadsheets");

  var form = app.createFormPanel();
  var flow = app.createFlowPanel();

  var label = app.createLabel("Select Spreadsheet where you want to copy the current sheet:").setId('selectLabel');
  flow.add(label);
  var allfiles =  DriveApp.getFiles();
  var verticalPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('verticalPanel');
  var i = 0;
  while (allfiles.hasNext())
  {
    var file = allfiles.next();
    var temp = app.createCheckBox(file.getName()).setName('cb'+i).setId('cb'+i);
    var tempvalue = app.createHidden('cbvalue'+i, file.getId());
    verticalPanel.add(temp);
    verticalPanel.add(tempvalue);
    i++;
  }

  var scrollPanel = app.createScrollPanel().setId('scrollPanel');
  scrollPanel.add(verticalPanel);
  scrollPanel.setSize("400", "250")
  flow.add(scrollPanel);

  var buttonsubmit = app.createSubmitButton("Copy");
  flow.add(buttonsubmit);

  form.add(flow);
  app.add(form);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
  return app;
}

function doPost(eventInfo) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var allfiles =  DriveApp.getFiles();
  var tempSsId = "";

  var i = 0;
  while (allfiles.hasNext())
  {
    var temp = eventInfo.parameter['cb'+i];
    if(temp == 'on')
    {
      tempSsId = eventInfo.parameter['cbvalue'+i];
      var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempSsId));
      activeSheet.setName(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName());
    }
    i++;
  }

  var label = app.createLabel('statusLabel');
  label.setText("Copied Active sheet in all selected Spreadsheets...");
  label.setVisible(true);
  app.add(label);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DriveApp.getFiles();` will get every file in your Drive.

`DriveApp.getFolderById('folder id').getFiles();` If you want to get files in a specific folder (this will get the files in that folder but not in subfolders).

This script has nothing to do with the question you asked and I think you may have worded your question incorrectly.

Do you mean you are attempting to copy an individual sheet from a spreadsheet to all of the other spreadsheets in a particular folder?

**EDIT**

```
function copyTo() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetName = ''; // ENTER THE NAME OF THE SHEET YOU WANT TO COPY
    var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(''); //ENTER THE ID OF THE TARGET FOLDER HERE
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var getFiles = targetFolder.getFiles();

    while (getFiles.hasNext()) {
        var file = getFiles.next();
        if (file.getMimeType() == 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet') {
            var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
            sheet.copyTo(targetSheet).setName(sheetName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do. I couldn't figure out how to easily do it, and this was a workaround (as it allows me to select files as tedious as that is). If you have an easy way to copy one sheet to multiple spreadsheet documents in a folder I would love to hear that.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had not used the getfolderid before. Also thank you, I had assumed that the while loop would just continue to run without a counter.